# Java equivalent to Ruby's `code if condition`

Tags: java

This has probably been asked before but I can't seem to find anything useful in Google (probably I'm looking for it wrong) nor here.

What is the equivalent (if there actually is one) of Ruby's `code if condition` in Java?

Example in Ruby (taken from TutorialsPoint):

```
$debug=1
print "debug\n" if $debug
```

In Java instead of doing

```
if (conditional) {
    doSomething();
}
```

I'd like to do something like

```
doSomething() if (conditional);
```

If I do

```
if (conditional) doSomething();
```

I get a warning with a suggestion to invert if.

Comment: could you post your actual code?

Comment: `if (conditional) doSomething();` works for me - no warning or similar. Can you describe it in more detail?

Comment: You can't; `if (xxx) {}` is just how Java works. "You get a warning to invert if" either means (a) you have a code inspection set up to detect "funky" conditionals, e.g., conditionals that read oddly the way written, or (b) there is no (b).

Comment: If you want Ruby syntax instead of Java syntax, maybe you should just use JRuby ([jruby.org](http://jruby.org/)).

Comment: The conditional is `if (sizeOfList1 + sizeOfList2 == 0)`, but as I was writing this comment, I understood that it was because of the lack parenthesis in the sum. I fixed it with `if ((sizeOfList1 + sizeOfList2) == 0)` and it's fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do that in Java, it isn't legal syntax.

You can do,

```
if (conditional) doSomething();
```

or

```
if (conditional) {
    doSomething();
}
```

or even change the signature of `doSomething()` to take a `boolean` and then

```
doSomething(conditional);
```

but you cannot add your desired syntax to the language without writing a pre-compiler.

For more see [JLS-14.9. The `if` Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9).

Comment: I think I'll go with the first one. Thanks for the answer. I'll accept as solution as soon as SO lets me

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent.  Ruby's statement is more syntactic sugar than anything else, as you can write the if statement in the same manner as you would in Java.

For Java, you're stuck wrapping your expressions in `if` statements:

```
if(conditional) {
    takeAction();
}
```